# How can we print the argument-list from args and kwargs?

Tags: python, python-3.x, parameter-passing, variadic-functions

Suppose that we have a variadic function, such as the following:

```
def foo(*args, **kwargs):
    pass
```

I would like to edit foo, so that it prints the argument-list. For example, we want the following code...

```
foo(98, 99, 100, a = 1, b = 2, c = 3)
```

... to print...

```
98, 99, 100, a = 1, b = 2, c = 3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will do pretty much what you want:

```
def foo(*args, **kwargs):
    print(args + tuple('{} = {}'.format(key,val) for key,val in kwargs.items()))
```

Answer (score 0):

The following seems to do the trick:

```
import itertools

rep_kwarg = lambda kwarg: kwarg[0] + " = " + str(kwarg[1])

def foo(*args, **kwargs):
    kwargs2 = map(rep_kwarg, kwargs.items())
    it_combo = itertools.chain(args, kwargs2)
    it_combo_str = map(str, it_combo)
    arg_list = ', '.join(it_combo_str)
    print("RESULT == ", repr(arg_list))


args = [98, 99, 100]
kwargs = {
    "a": 1,
    "b": 2,
    "c": 3
}
foo(*args, **kwargs)
foo(98, 99, 100, a = 1, b = 2, c = 3)
```

The console output is:

```
RESULT ==  '98, 99, 100, a = 1, b = 2, c = 3'
RESULT ==  '98, 99, 100, a = 1, b = 2, c = 3'
```